# how launch Vagrant box inside Windows if it is made inside Mac?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I am taking udemy course 'Learning Yii 2' and the guy offers to use a Vagrant box, which he created on Mac via puphpet.

Unfortunately he thinks that 'folder source' is here `/Users/mjbeaumont/Packt/Code`, while I plan to set it here `f:/dev/vagrant/sites/mjbeaumont/code`. It's clear, that Vagrant from Mac within his box refuses to agree with me, while I am on Windows.

Does it mean, that rumours about Vagrant total OS cross-compatibility are lies? Or there is a way to solve my problem?

Comment: maybe you can link to the project (if its on github) so it might be easier to check but you can just change the path for the shared folder setting and everything will work wether you're on mac or windows

Comment: Thanks for support,- but where and how can I change the path for the shared foder setting?

Comment: open the Vagrantfile and look at the `synced_folder` setting

Comment: Thank you! - I found this block in 'config.yaml': 'synced_folder' >> 'source: 'f:/dev/vagrant/sites/mjbeaumont/code' >> 'target: /var/www'. You saved my life